# Stata estpost esttab: Generate table with mean of variable split by year and group

Tags: stata

I want to create a table in Stata with the `estout` package to show the mean of a variable split by 2 groups (year and binary indicator) in an efficient way.

I found a solution, which is to split the main variable cash_at into 2 groups by hand through the generation of new variables, e.g. cash_at1 and cash_at2. Then, I can generate summary statistics with tabstat and get output with esttab.

```
estpost tabstat cash_at1 cash_at2, stat(mean) by(year)
esttab, cells("cash_at1 cash_at2")
```

Link to current result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIYMe.jpg

However, I'd prefer a horizontal table (e.g. year on the x axis) and a way to do it without splitting the groups by hand - is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My preference in these cases is for **year** to be in rows and the statistic (e.g. mean) in the columns, but if you want to do it the other way around, there should be no problem.

For a table like the one you want it suffices to have the binary variable you already mention (which I name **flag**) and appropriate labeling. You can use the built-in `table` command:

```
clear all
set more off

* Create example data
set seed 8642
set obs 40

egen year = seq(), from(1985) to (2005) block(4)
gen cash = floor(runiform()*500)
gen flag = round(runiform())
list, sepby(year)

* Define labels
label define lflag 0 "cash0" 1 "cash1"
label values flag lflag

* Table
table flag year, contents(mean cash)
```

In general, for tables, apart from the `estout` module you may want to consider also the user-written command `tabout`. Run `ssc describe tabout` for more information.

On the other hand, it's not clear what you mean by "splitting groups by hand". You show no code for this operation, but as long as it's general enough for your purposes (and practical) I think you should allow for it. The code might not be as *elegant* as you wish but if it's doing what it's supposed to, I think it's alright. For example:

```
clear all
set more off

set seed 8642
set obs 40

* Create example data
egen year = seq(), from(1985) to (2005) block(4)
gen cash = floor(runiform()*500)
gen flag = round(runiform())

* Data management
gen cash0 = cash if flag == 0
gen cash1 = cash if flag == 1

* Table
estpost tabstat cash*, stat(mean) by(year)
esttab, cells("cash0 cash1")
```

can be used for a table like the one you give in your original post. It's true you have two extra lines and variables, but they may be harmless. I agree with the idea that in general, efficiency is something you worry about once your program is behaving appropriately; unless of course, the lack of it prevents you from reaching that state.